# Terminal dpkg error

Tags: dpkg, themes

I am trying to install this theme: https://github.com/andreisergiu98/arc-flatabulous-theme but I need to install git first, and this error shows up:

```
~$ sudo apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-26 linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic
  linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-26-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-26-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic (5.4.0-39.43) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic (5.4.0-39.43) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-39-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 34: /etc/default/grub: blacklist: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic package post-installation script subproc
ess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-39-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit: `cat /etc/default/grub` output:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
blacklist radeon
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920X1080X32
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.dc=1 amdgpu.dpm=1 amdgpu.modeset=1"
```

Comment: Why do you have `blacklist radeon` in line 34? This is an invalid entry for grub file.  Was it supposed to be something else?  Run `sudoedit /etc/default/grub`, remove that line and save the file. Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and retry the installation of git.